# How to use elasticsearch script based sorting in yii

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, yii2

I'm using `yii\elasticsearch\Query`, and I want to use the script based sorting, as described [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting). I do not see any possibility with Yii.

I can not define the field at the indexing, because I have to sort by the sum of 2 or more fields. Which fields are involved in the sorting is dynamic.

I've tried to define a script field on the fly, what is allowed by Yii:

```
$query->fields = array_merge($allFields, [
    'rda_sum' => "doc['nutrient_220_rda_rate'].value + doc['nutrient_221_rda_rate'].value",
]);
```

But unfortunately the script field can not be used in the `orderBy` method. I get the the error message:

```
No mapping found for [rda_sum] in order to sort on
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you get this problem figured out?

Comment: No. As I see the PHP code of yii\elasticsearch\Query, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution would be to apply it as a score rather than a calculated field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

And if you need to the opposite order, multiply the result of your score calculation by -1

Comment: Thx, but I have to set the ordering on the fly, because the fields involved in the sorting are varying. Otherwise I don't see, how I should use your solution with yii\elasticsearch\Query.